# How to select certain text between HTML tags but not Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, cheerio

What I am trying to achieve is for example given an HTML string like the following:

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text, some text <span> some text</span> <a href="xxx">some text 
  <span>ZZZ</span></a></p>
  <p>some text, some text, <span>ZZZ</span></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>some text <span>ZZZ</span></p>
</div>
```

I am required to find the first matching "ZZZ" that is not in `<a>` tag
So the correct answer is the second ZZZ appeared in the above HTML string

I am currently using Cheerio JS, but instead of looping through every element and try to determine if there is a `<a>` parent, is there a simpler way?

I have tried regular expression like `<([\w]+)[^>]*>(.*?)ZZZ(.*?)<\/\1>` and loop through all instances to determine if the encapsulating tag is `<a>` or not. But I couldn't wrap my head around it to consider nested tags.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with a regular expression. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: <([^a]+)[^>]*>(.*?)ZZZ(.*?)<\/\1>

Answer (score 2):

I think looping though the element might be a easier way to do this...

```js
let target = null;

// find the element that inner text is 'ZZZ' and not in an a tag
let find = e => 
  !target && (
    (e.innerText === 'ZZZ' && e.tagName !== 'A' && (target = e)) || 
    (e.tagName !== 'A' && e.childElementCount > 0 && [...e.children].forEach(find))
  );

[...document.body.children].forEach(find);

console.log(target);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text, some text <span> some text</span><a href="xxx">some text 
  <span id="1">ZZZ</span></a></p>
  <p>some text, some text, <span id="2">ZZZ</span></p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>some text <span id="3">ZZZ</span></p>
</div>
```